# Run executable jar from command line fails due to missing library

Tags: java, maven, jar, wsdl, classpath

I created an executable jar from maven with the following build config:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.targetName}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <excludeScope>test</excludeScope>
                <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <packageName>${project.build.packageName}</packageName>
                <mainClass>${project.build.packageName}.${project.build.className}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
        <finalName>${project.build.targetName}/${project.build.targetName}</finalName>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Which generated the following files:

```
./lib/axis-2878297.jar
./lib/axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
./lib/(other dependencies jars)
./target.jar
```

1.If I run this jar from command line in this way:

```
java -jar target.jar
```

It produces the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/OperationType
        at org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc.<clinit>(OperationDesc.java:59)
        ...
```

2.If I run it in the other way:

```
java -cp "target.jar;lib\*" com.test.Main
```

The execution will be successful.

**P.S.** I tried to put -verbose:class to the commands.

For case 1 it shows:

```
[Loaded org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc from file:/C:/build/lib/axis-2878297.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74\lib\rt.jar]
[...]
```

While for case 2 it shows:

```
[Loaded org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc from file:/C:/build/lib/axis-2878297.jar]
[Loaded javax.wsdl.OperationType from file:/C:/build/lib/axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar]
[...]
```

What is reason that case 1 fails?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the MANIFEST.MF file in target.jar.  The Class-Path line should explicitly mention all your lib/* files, with a correct relative path name starting from target.jar.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thanks for the hint. It's interesting that in MANIFEST.MF all jars under lib are included in Class-Path except the axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar.

Answer (score 2):

OK I got the reason:

In pom.xml I set the scope of axis-wsdl4j to "provided", which indicates I expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. So when maven writes the manifest.mf it skips this dependency.

Thanks for all the answers and helps.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work using the [Maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

I used a tutorial by [Mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/).

The demo app is a command line app that uses Joda time:

```
package com.mykong.core.utils;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

/**
 * Hello world!
 * @link http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/
 */
public class App {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getLocalCurrentDate());
    }

    private static String getLocalCurrentDate() {
        String result = "";
        try {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("enter getLocalCurrentDate");
            }
            result = new LocalDate().toString();
        } finally {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("exit getLocalCurrentDate");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's my pom.xml; adapt it to your purposes.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mykong.core.utils</groupId>
  <artifactId>dateUtils</artifactId>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dateUtils</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>dateutils</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>com.mykong.core.utils.App</Main-Class>
                            <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```